# Velocity Template - Show and Hide

Tags: java, templates, velocity, velocity-template-language

I have the following velocity template.

```
    <tr>
    <td>Address 1*</td>
    <td>:<b> $currentAddressAddress1 </b> </td>
    </tr>
    #if ($currentAddressAddress2)
    <tr>
    <td>Address 2</td>
    <td>:<b> $!currentAddressAddress2 </b> </td>
    </tr>
    #end
```

The second row should be displayed only if `currentAddressAddress2` has **value** in it. Otherwise it should not display. But I am getting the following as output

> Address 1* : RJ street
>
> Address 2 :
>
> But I want ,
>
> Address 1* : RJ street

only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nulls in velocity are very fiddly (this will provide some insight on how to check for nulls: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/velocity/CheckingForNull). I'm assuming `$currentAddressAddress2` is a `String`? In which case if it is not null then your check will return `true`. There are a few options available, but one is:

```
#if($!currentAddressAddress2 != "")
```

This is obviously not a great solution, it doesn't cater for blank strings for example, only empty. One other option is you could add Apache StringUtils into your request from your controller and use `isNotEmpty` to check it has a "real" value.